# Executing a bash script from a windows bat file

Tags: windows, linux, rpc

Is there a way to call a bash script? (Or any linux like command) from a batch file (or VB script) on a windows box?

Thanks
K

Comment: With Cygwin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810966/automate-cygwin-via-batch-file/3869932#3869932

Answer (score 1):

If you have Cygwin installed then a line like this in your batch file should run the bash script:

`bash scriptname.sh`